# How show minibuffer's history of commands

Tags: minibuffer, commands, history-variables

windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Helm

I open buffer ***scratch***

and execute 3 commands sequence:

1. `M-x I-search`
2. `helm-occur`
3. `replace-string`

here sreenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Nice. It's work fine.
But now I want to show in list all of this commands in stack mode.

Smt like this:

```
replace-string
helm-occur
I-search
```

And then I want to select one of them (e.g. `I-search`) and execute them.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to have commands that you previously entered at the `M-x` prompt available as *completion* candidates, then [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) can help.

There are [several ways](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_History_Enhancements) in which you can use completion against candidates from minibuffer histories. One simple one is to use **`M-h`**. For example, `M-x M-h` shows your `M-x` inputs in buffer `*Completions*`. You can type text to complete  or just cycle to the command you want, etc.

---

UPDATE to reply to comment question:

You can download Icicles from [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispArea). See [Downloading Icicles Libraries](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Libraries#BulkIciclesDownload).

Comment: Where I can download package "icicles"? In MELPA it not found

Comment: @Alexei: Updated answer to provide that info. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you already use helm - as you gave the example of helm-occur. Helm comes with helm-minibuffer-history - try

```
M-x helm-minibuffer-history
```

The usual way of selecting helm candidates works here too.

Comment: I get error: helm-M-x: Error: Attempt to use minibuffer history outside a minibuffer

Comment: Known bug : https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/1655. Update your helm, restart emacs to be sure, and then try again.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. Even with an updated helm and a restarted Emacs, I still get the same error as @a_subscriber.

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of minibuffer histories, each recording minibuffer input for various calls to `completing-read`.

You seem to be looking for the history of **commands** entered at the `M-x` prompt. Variable `extended-command-history` records that history. So just use `C-h v extended-command-history` to see the list in `*Help*`, or just evaluate `extended-command-history` in Lisp to get the list.

Comment: No customizable group, face, or option matching (extended-command-history)

Comment: Minibuffer history variables, and `extended-command-history`, are not user options. They are used to record minibuffer input. You or Lisp code can use them (including reset any of them) at any time. `C-h v` shows a list value for `extended-command-history`: the commands you invoked using `M-x`. In the example you cite, you apparently invoked (only) those 4 commands using `M-x`.

Comment: I want to select command from list (like helm do). Not like this: extended-command-history is a variable defined in ‘simple.el’.
Its value is
("helm-occur" "yafolding-hide-element" "json-pretty-print" "yafolding-show-element" "highlight-symbol-remove-all" "magit-status" "customize-variable" "rename-buffer" "magit-list-repositories" "new-frame")